# Create new Array under same key from multiple Array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, arraylist

I have the following array.

```
$a = array("Algebra", "Arithmetic");
$b = array("08/01/2020", "08/02/2019");
$c = array("08/01/2020", "08/02/2019");

print_r($a);
print_r($b);
print_r($b);
```

and the output is

```
Array(
    [0] => Algebra
    [1] => Arithmetic
  )

Array(
    [0] => 08/01/2020
    [1] => 08/01/2019
  )

Array(
    [0] => 08/02/2020
    [1] => 08/02/2019
  )
```

And I want Array in the following structure.

```
Array(
 [0] => Algebra,08/01/2020,08/02/2020
 [1] => Arithmetic,08/01/2019,08/02/2019
)
```

I have tried `$results = array_merge_recursive($a, $b, $c);` but its not giving desire output.

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: You want to convert the arrays into a comma delimited list?

Comment: Please show your input array using `print_r()` or `var_dump()` or even better `var_export()` so it looks like a real array or is it 3 seperate arrays

Comment: You have 3 different arrays or one multidimensional array?

Comment: @FelippeDuarte I have 3 different array.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I have updated the question showing the input array and print_r() also. And required arrays value in comma delimited list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple foreach loop will suffice

```
$a = array("Algebra", "Arithmetic");
$b = array("08/01/2020", "08/02/2019");
$c = array("08/01/2020", "08/02/2019");

foreach( $a as $i=>$v ) {
    $new[] = sprintf( '%s,%s,%s', $v, $b[$i], $c[$i] );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't get anything built-in for this purpose. You need to build a custom function for this. You can try this-

```
<?php
$a = array("Algebra", "Arithmetic");
$b = array("08/01/2020", "08/01/2019");
$c = array("08/02/2020", "08/02/2019");

function mergeAssoc()
{
    // You can get variable number of arguments|array by this.
    $args = func_get_args();

    $master = array();

    foreach ($args as $arg)
    {
        foreach ($arg as $i => $v)
        {
            $master[$i][] = $v;
        }
    }

    return $master;
}

$res = mergeAssoc($a, $b, $c);

print_r($res);
```

**Note:** It will return a multidimensional array. Not an array of comma-separated values.

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Algebra
            [1] => 08/01/2020
            [2] => 08/02/2020
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Arithmetic
            [1] => 08/01/2019
            [2] => 08/02/2019
        )

)
```

and if we use `foreach` then our desire output will be there with array separated by comma.

```
foreach ($res as $key => $value) {
 $result[] = implode(',', $value);
}
```

and output of `print_r($result);` is

```
Array
 (
  [0] => Algebra,08/01/2020,08/02/2020
  [1] => Arithmetic,08/01/2019,08/02/2019
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, when you find yourself using sequentially-named variables it almost always means that they should actually be an array:

```
$a = array("Algebra", "Arithmetic");
$b = array("08/01/2020", "08/02/2019");
$c = array("08/01/2020", "08/02/2019");

$better_array = [$a, $b, $c];
var_dump($better_array);
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(7) "Algebra"
    [1]=>
    string(10) "Arithmetic"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "08/01/2020"
    [1]=>
    string(10) "08/02/2019"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "08/01/2020"
    [1]=>
    string(10) "08/02/2019"
  }
}
```

Once they're in an proper array you can use [`array_column()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)

```
$out = [];
for($i=0, $c=count($better_array[0]); $i < $c; ++$i) {
    $out[] = array_column($better_array, $i);
}
var_dump($out);
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(7) "Algebra"
    [1]=>
    string(10) "08/01/2020"
    [2]=>
    string(10) "08/01/2020"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "Arithmetic"
    [1]=>
    string(10) "08/02/2019"
    [2]=>
    string(10) "08/02/2019"
  }
}
```

And if that comma-delimited string is what you actually want, then use `implode()`:

```
$out = [];
for($i=0, $c=count($better_array[0]); $i < $c; ++$i) {
    $out[] = implode(',', array_column($better_array, $i));
}
var_dump($out);
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(29) "Algebra,08/01/2020,08/01/2020"
  [1]=>
  string(32) "Arithmetic,08/02/2019,08/02/2019"
}
```

Lastly, you should avoid `print_r()` as it tends to produce misleading output. Eg: https://3v4l.org/ThSLb